# WinForm .exe application loads a blank screen when published

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, cefsharp

I have an antique application using cefsharp.commons dll and I had to update a small part for the api communication.
The problem is that when I run the application on visual studio it works perfectly but when I publish, it installs but loads a blank screen instead of the usual UI.

I've searched different articles on ways to publish using clickonce and it seems the publish its correct.
I´ve also saw the logs on the event viewer application on windows and I have the following messages

> Name of application failing: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe, version 43.0.0.0 name of failing module: KERNELBASE.dll

also:

> Excpetion: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> em CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Program.Main(System.String[])

But the enviromment runs the previous version so i dont think my windows is missing any dependencies.

I would really appreciate any help.

best regards.

Comment: Look for another event in your Windows Event Log with the stack-trace of the crash.

Comment: I have a IO exception withoud any details. System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   em CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Program.Main(System.String[])

Comment: Maybe you built for 64 bit instead of 32 bit - so its doing something like looking in C:\Program Files instead of C:\Program Files (x86)...

Comment: Review the changes you made in source control. You are missing some files from the published version.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my application was not caring the cefsharp files when the clickonce application generates the dlls on the receiving computer.

The solution I had to do was manually add the dlls on the project folder (On the roots, besides having it on the reference added).

it is certainly some bug between generating the deploy dependencies and generating it back on installation.

Comment: The version you are using is 5 years old, if you were using the latest supported version (v84 at time of writing) then there are much simpler options.